# animation of polylines in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, animation

I would like to think with all the animations out there thsi would be relatively simple but it hasn't been.

I would like to animate the movement of a stream (polyline) from one end to another, with all its forks and tributaries (smaller polylines).  I have been reduced  to trying the Time Stamp property in ArcGIS 10.  I have a number of questions related to this, such as why is it that the Time Stamp property always defaults to hours, or that if I try to alter the time property to a different time step, it causes the one segment I have been working with to disappear?

If anyone has worked with the time stamp property in ArcGIS 10 successfully for a whole layer I would love to hear from you.

Dan Brenner
Eureka, CA

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I would like to do something similar by showing oil travel from the point of the spill into a nearby waterway and how quickly it will travel down the stream. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Some features require ArcScene for animation like http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Following_an_object_along_a_path/000900000050000000/

**Temporal data** is different to animated layers - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_time_properties_on_data/005z0000000q000000/

Full list of supported Time (temporal) fields are:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Supported_field_formats/005z00000006000000/