# How to create Sequential Animation of Polylines in ArcGIS10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, time, animation

I have a data set consisting of sets of polylines which reflect movement of individual organisms in my sample within their habitat each day. I am trying to create an animation which cycles through the days, displaying only the movement for one day at a time.

When I try to do this in ArcGIS10, it adds the lines from each day onto a map containing the lines from all previous days. How can I get the previous days' lines to disappear when the time slider moves to the next day?

Comment: You should now have enough reputation to post screenshots. Please do so, along with detailed information about your data and what steps you took to set up your animation.

Comment: There is a similar but not identical question [**here**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2874/animation-of-polylines-in-arcgis-10) that does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

- I created a new feature class of type line that I called TestLines with one date field I called MovementDate
- I created three line features, the second and third starting from the ends of the first and second, and then put movement dates of 9/1/13, 10/1/13 and 11/1/13 (Australian date format so these represent 9-11 Jan)
- I made the settings below on the **Animation** tab of this layer's Properties

[image]

- On the **Animation** toolbar I chose **Animation | Create Time Animation**
- I then used **Animation | Animation Manager** to open the Animation Manager where the **Track** tab confirmed that I had one **Time Animation Track**
- On the **Keyframes** tab of the Animation Manager there were two **Time Keyframes** for 9/1/13 and 11/1/13 so I used the **Create** button to make another one for 10/1/13, the arrows to get it in the right time order, and also set the Interval and Units for each to be 1 day

[image]

- I then hit **Open Animation Controls** on the Animation toolbar and made the settings below.  I also hit the **Calculate** button.

[image]

- Final step was to hit the **Play** button on the Animation Controls and what I observed was the first day's movement only on for a second, then the second day's movement on for a second, then the third day's movement on for a second, followed by all three days movement at once which stayed on.

Comment: Thanks! This a really clear and helpful answer. I've now got it working perfectly.